# In c++, std::string::size() does not count modified string length

Tags: c++, string

My code is below :

```
int main(){
    string s = "abcd";
    int length_of_string = s.size();
    cout<<length_of_string<<endl;
    s[length_of_string] = 'e';
    s[length_of_string+1] = 'f';
    int length_of_string2 = s.size();
    cout<<length_of_string2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, every string is terminated with a NULL character. In my code I declare a string  with length of 4. Then I print the length_of_string which gives a value of 4. Then I modify it and add two characters, 'e' at index 4 and 'f' at index of 5. Now my string has 6 characters. But when I read its length again it shows me that the length is 4, but my string length is 6.

How does s.size() function is work in this case. Is it not the count until NULL character?

Comment: the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) shows that accessing at `size` position of a string array is undefined

Comment: A string literal and a C string are terminated by `\0`, but you cannot assume the same for `std::string`. Also, when you write to elements of the string beyond the size of the string, you are engaging in undefined behaviour and *anything* can happen - in any case, the code is *broken/wrong*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to push a character at the end of the string you should use `std::string::push_back` function as:

```
int main(){
    string s = "abcd";
    int length_of_string = s.size();
    cout<<length_of_string<<endl;
    s.push_back('e');
    s.push_back('f');
    int length_of_string2 = s.size();
    cout<<length_of_string2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

The length of a `std::string` is returned by `size()`.

Although you are allowed to use `[]` to modify characters in the string prior to the index `size()`, you are not allowed to modify characters *on or after* that.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: Nothing says a `std::string` is null terminated.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Indeed, that is a very good point. I've reworded.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: C++11 says a `std::string` is null-terminated. In particular, `std::basic_string<CH>::operator[](size_type pos)` returns `CH{0}` when `pos==`std::basic_string<CH>::size()`. This is a change from C++98.